# iOS Webview Detect When Keyboard is open?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, webview

I have a fixed footer in a webpage that I'm displaying in an iOS webview. In Mozilla/Chrome, when the keyboard opens the footer jumps to the top of the keyboard which is ideal (I'm guessing the webview itself is resized when the keyboard is triggered?).

In Safari it stays at the bottom hidden by the keyboard, which is kind of annoying because I need that continue button available to the user. So the user has to close the keyboard to get to the button which is a suboptimal experience.

Likewise in the iOS webview, it's also hidden.

It seems like maybe the ideal situation is to adjust the webview's height when the keyboard is shown (though I'm open to other ideas/suggestions).

Does anyone know how I would go about watching when the keyboard appears so that I could adjust the height of the fullscreen webivew based on the keyboard's dimensions?

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *fullURL = @"localhost:3000/campaigns";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self


                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification

                                       object:nil];





- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification{




// Get the size of the keyboard.

CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] 


objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


//Given size may not account for screen rotation

int height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

int width = MAX(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

//finding screensize

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;


//Setting Screen Size


 CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;

    frame.size.height = "your height in int";

    aWebView.frame = frame;

    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    frame.size = fittingSize;

    aWebView.frame = frame;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { (sender) in
    print("Keyboard did show")
}
```

This may be called more than once